How to concatenate various jpgs pngs and pdf into single pdf leaving their sizes as they where?
I am trying to make a kind of dossier out of various pngs,jpgs and single page pdf images. It has to be a single pdf file, but it doesn't matter that results into something conveniently printable. As such, each page can be whatever size and format whatsoever. I have seen answers here that show how to make them into nice same-size pages, or center them, or such, but my interest is exactly the opposite. The order is already solved as the filenames are nicely numbered. If I try with pdfunite (after a convert), it makes them fit into letter paper pages. Using convert directly also makes them fit them into letter paper pages, but it crops images that are to wide.

Assuming the files can be enumerated with a simple * wildcard (based on "The order is already solved as the filenames are nicely numbered"), we can use a loop like this:
#!/bin/sh
k=1
mkdir t

for f in *
do
    [ ! -f "$f" ] && continue

    echo "Processing $f" >&2
    case "${f##*.}" in
    jpg)
        jpegtopnm "$f" | pnmtops | ps2pdf - t/"$(printf '%03d' "$k")" ;;
    pdf)
        ln "$f" t/ ;;
    png)
        pnmtops "$f" | ps2pdf - t/"$(printf '%03d' "$k")" ;;
    *)
        echo "Unexpected format, skipping: $f" >&2 ;;
    esac
    k=$((k+1))
done

pdftk t/*.pdf cat output RESULT.pdf
rm -rf t


Interesting, but it doesn't get the job done. Firstly, by some reason it only procesess 16 out of 31 files (two had wrong ending but i corrected that). More to the point: some large images are "corrected" to fit into the letterpaper size, which is what I want to avoid. The medium images are correctly handed, though. Thanks.

Ok. Sorry.It does work. It seems that my viewer (zathura) is the source of my confussion. In another machine (an old Mac with other viewer) the final doc was as it was desired. (also using pdfunite works).
